# If $\omega_1$ is inaccessible to the reals, then every $\mathbf{\Sigma}_2^1$ set has the Baire property

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Consider the following proof of the assertion in the title:

> Say $A=\{x\in 2^\omega: \phi(x,y)\}$, where $\phi$ is a $\Sigma_2^1$ formula and $y\in 2^\omega$. 
>   By Shoenfield's absoluteness, 
>   $$x\in A \iff L(x,y)\models \phi(x,y)$$
>   Because $\omega_1$ is inaccessible to the reals, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{P})\cap L(z)$ is countable for every $z\in 2^\omega$, where $\mathbb{P}=\text{Fn}(\omega,2)$ is Cohen forcing.  Therefore, the set 
>   $$\{g\in 2^\omega: g\text{ is Cohen generic over }L(z)\}$$
>   is comeager. Now, for every Cohen generic $g$ over $L(y)$, 
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> g\in A&\iff L(y,g)\models \phi(g,y)\\
> &\iff \exists n<\omega \left[g\upharpoonright n  \Vdash^{L(y)}\phi(\dot g,\check y)\right]\\
> &\iff g\in \bigcup\left\{N_s\cap 2^\omega: s\Vdash^{L(y)} \phi(\dot g,\check y)\right\}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   and this set is open.

Now, the title of the question is a theorem of ZFC. However, when looking at the proof, I'm confused, because we're $L(x,y)$ and $L(y,g)$ are proper classes, and we're dealing with $L(x,y)\models \phi(x,y)$ for all $\Sigma_2^1$ formulas at once. And we can't write $N\models \psi$ as a property of the set $\psi$ (assuming we've formalized first order logic in ZFC) when $N$ is a proper class by Tarski's Undefinability of Truth. We can metalinguistically define $\psi^N$ one formula at a time, but this does not seem to be the spirit of the proof. Moreover, one can define $\mathbf{\Sigma}_2^1$ without any logic (say, as projections of co-analytic sets).

Is there a flaw in my reasoning? How should one reconcile these points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interpret a $\Sigma^1_2$ formula in $L(x,y)$, you don't need a notion of truth in the whole proper class $L(x,y)$. Since the formula involves quantification only over reals, you can just interpret it in the set of reals of $L(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks! If I may, I have a follow up question that just occurred to me: would something similar hold with $\Vdash$ in place of $\models$? More precisely, the Truth Lemma $M[G]\models \phi \iff \exists p\in G(p\Vdash \phi)$ is a theorem for set sized models and a scheme for classes. Can one salvage it by saying that, in this case, the quantifiers are bounded by $2^\omega$ or $\omega$?

Comment: @Reveillark One can salvage this sort of thing by bounding the quantifiers, but the necessary bound would depend on the notion $\mathbb P$ of forcing. Essentially, you can let the quantifiers range over a set big enough to contain all the necessary names of reals. More precisely, although there's no set containing all of the $\mathbb P$-names of reals, there is a set $S$ such that, whenever $\mathbb P\Vdash x\in\mathbb R$, there is some $y\in S$ with $\mathbb P\Vdash x=y$. Use such an $S$ to bound the quantifiers.